# Play online video using Google Cardboard in my Android app

Tags: google-cardboard

I want to play video in my Android app and the video placed at my online server. The video is in YouTube 360 format.
 I read about vrtoolkit and vrvideoview at github but it plays the video which is saved locally that is it is saved in Android device.

I want to my online video Google cardboard feature.
So what's best possible way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

use uri to load the video

fileUri =  Uri.parse( "http://your-url-to video file" );
videoWidgetView.loadVideo(fileUri);